# how to remove / disavow a private podspec?

Tags: cocoapods

Recently, I found a problem in a public cocoapod, and I was impatient to wait for the fix. Good thing, too, because it took about 4 weeks to get my PR accepted.

So, my solution was to fork the public pod. I'm already using a private repo for some of my company's private pods, so I modified my forked podspec file, and did a `pod repo push` to my local repo.

In my podfile, I modified the "pod" line like so:

```
 pod 'PublicPod', :git => "https://github.com/MyCompany/ForkedPublicPod.git
```

Recently, my PR was accepted, so I removed the "git" dependency on the "PublicPod" line, telling Cocoapods to use the "normal" pod, instead of my private pod (or so I thought). However, I'm being told that cocoapods has `Found multiple declarations for 'PublicPod'`.

So, I don't need my forked pod to be active anymore, but I do have other private pods, so I can't just removed the `source` line from my Podfile.

I just want to forget about my private pod, and have it just not be seen or available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced the similar problem. I haven't found any command to do this via pods, so I completed this task manually. I removed my local pod the next way:

1. Remove folder with all podspecs from my private pod. I think, this is the main step because no podspecs - no pod.
2. Run `pod repo update [repo_name]` to stay your local cached repo synced with remote repo.
3. Since I don't need my current sources for the removed pod, I delete them too.
4. I use tags for pod versioning, so I remove all tags connected to my pod
5. Additionally you can clean pod cache (to be ensure, that you really use remote pod) with `pod cache clean <pod_name> --all`. **Be careful**, if you miss `pod_name`, this command will clear all your cache (all pods)!

I suppose, the first two steps are enough. But I wanted to completely remove the private pod.